# Does the slogan「やればやるほどディスクシステム」only mean, "if you play, play more, Disk System"?

Tags: meaning, translation, video-games

There are a lot of different translations out there all over the web for this slogan. This is the one I generally trust the most since it appears on page 4 of the book "Hardcore Gaming 101 Presents: The Complete Guide to the Famicom Disk System [Kalata, Kurt, Hubbard, Dustin]"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVL0W.jpg

> "If you play, play more, Disk System"

I wanted to know, from a grammatical point of view, can the construction ば~ほど (ba~hodo) be somehow stretched here for this slogan to thus have more translations or does the grammar coincide with the book's sentence correctly?

Comment: Perhaps [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W1xJtMOMVnM) is a better source for the slogan mentioned in your question (it's a Famicon ad).

Answer (score 2):

[The ～ば～ほど construction](https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%81%B0%EF%BD%9E%E3%81%BB%E3%81%A9-ba-hodo-meaning/) must be followed by a predicative expression (a verb or an adjective, typically ～ようになる), but this slogan has a bare noun instead. So the most literal translation is just "The more you play... (the more you say it's) Disk System".

According to my intuition, the latter half of the slogan is an abbreviated version of something along the lines of "the more you will like Disk System", "the more you'll likely to choose Disk System" or "the more you'll receive the benefit of Disk System". I guess this slogan is not about the pure play time, but about the overall benefit of the system you'll gradually receive. The Disk System can seem complicated at first, and the cost advantage will be achieved only after rewriting a disk many times.